# MTG Conspiracy cards allowed in modern

Tags: magic-the-gathering, deck-building, mtg-modern

So I always thought that the Conspiracy set was allowed in Modern Format but I recently discovered that there are 65 cards that are not allowed. Can any give me a list or a link for a list of the cards that are or are not allowed in Modern play?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cards from Conspiracy are not legal in Modern unless they were already printed in a Modern legal set. There were 65 new cards in that set, 52 are legal in Legacy and Vintage the remaining 13 are not legal in any Constructed format. The 13 that aren't legal are the ones with the [Conspiracy type](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?action=advanced&special=true&type=%20[Conspiracy]).

The only things that add new cards to the Modern card pool are sets that are Standard legal. Supplementary sets like Conspiracy, Commander, or Planechase do not, new cards from those sets are only legal in Legacy and Vintage.

Comment: For a visual list of the 100 CNS cards that are modern legal you can head over here: https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=f%3Amodern+e%3Acns

Comment: This is no longer entirely correct. The Modern Horizons sets were never standard legal, but were made legal directly into Modern.

Answer (score 0):

The modern legal sets are as follows.

Core sets from 8th Edition on wards. This includes

- 8th Edition
- 9th Edition
- 10th Edition
- Magic 2010
- Magic 2011
- Magic 2012
- Magic 2013
- Magic 2014
- Magic 2015
- Magic Origins

The following blocks are also part of the modern format.

- Mirrodin Block (Mirrodin, Fifth Dawn and Darksteel.)
- Kamigawa Block (Champions, Betrayers and Saviors of Kamigawa.)
- Ravnica Block (Ravnica: City of Guilds, Guildpact and Dissension.)
- Time Spiral Block (Time Spiral, Planar Chaos and Future Sight.)
- Lorwyn Block (Lorwyn and Morningtide)
- Shadowmoor Block (Shadowmoor and Eventide.)
- Shard of Alara Block (Shards of Alara, Conflux and Alara Reborn)
- Zendikar Block (Zendikar and Worldwake.)
- Rise of the Eldrazi Block (Stand Alone.)
- Scars of Mirrodin Block (Scars of Mirrodin, Mirrodin Besieged and New Phyrexia.)
- Innistrad Block (Innistrad, Dark Ascension and Avacyn Restored.)
- Return to Ravnica Block (Return to Ravnica, Gatecrash and Dragon's Maze.)
- Theros Block (Theros, Born of the Gods and Journey into Nyx)
- Khans of Tarkir Block (Khans of Tarkir, Fate Reforged and Dragons of Tarkir.
- Battle for Zendikar Block (Battle for Zendikar, Oath of the Gatewatch.)

Unless cards have been printed in one of these sets they are not legal for the modern format. Although the format bears the Title of Modern there is plenty of cards printed with the modern card frame that are not legal for this format.

EDIT:

Oh and do remember there is a banned list of cards as well. Do make sure you are not playing any of them.

EDIT:

Do note some of the conspiracy cards are modern legal seeing as they have been printed in a modern legal set before. Reflecting Pool comes to mind.